# maintaining constant width while moving a surface

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image: width with 25mm]
[image: width less than 25mm]

I want to join the selected face to the diagonal geometry at an angle. I extruded the following face of width 25mm, however when i move it along to join it, its thickness is decreasing.
is there a better way to do it?